# Airflow - How to get list of upstream failed tasks?

Tags: airflow

Consider a DAG where tasks `A`, `B`, and `C` have a downstream task `all_success`, that waits for all of upstream to be successful.

```
a = run_this = BashOperator(task_id='run_after_loop', bash_command='exit 1',)
b = run_this = BashOperator(task_id='run_after_loop', bash_command='exit 0',)
c = run_this = BashOperator(task_id='run_after_loop', bash_command='exit 1',)

all_success = DummyOperator(task_id='all_success', trigger_rule='all_success',)
a >> all_success
b >> all_success
c >> all_success
```

What I can replace `all_success` with, that will show (stdout in code) the list of all upstream tasks that failed for this particular DAG run?

Edit: I know I can see it in UI, but I'm looking to get the list in a stdout. My use case is that I have some huge DAGs with hundreds of tasks, all followed by a single downstream task. If any of the upstream tasks fail, it's very hard to scroll through the UI to find what all failed.

Comment: I not sure about what you are asking. you want to know how many fail? Run all_success even if one fail?. Because list of all upstream tasks that failed for this particular DAG run. This info you see it in the airflow interface directly, all dags that failed are red.

Comment: Not how many, but what all failed. I added some more information in the question under "Edit" about why UI is not the best solution for my use case. Probably I confused the question by adding the `all_success` example.

Comment: It is possible. I will try to answer tomorrow night. I don't have my computer over the weekend and cannot answer from the phone

Comment: @LucasM.Uriarte any luck? :)

Answer (score 1):

Okay, So I have faced the same problem when I wanted to report the task that failed to an external system. This proved to be simple after banging my head for a hour or so - being a newbie in Airflow, I still confuse between the Task and the `TaskInstance`, but anyway here's the recipe:

```py
def get_failed_upstream_tasks():
    # We need both the current run and the current task instance 
    dag_run: DagRun = get_current_context().get('dag_run')
    ti: TaskInstance = get_current_context().get('ti')

    # This is what took me a while - to figure out that the direct relatives 
    # are defined on the Task and not on the TaskInstance. True - for upstream
    upstream_tasks: list[BaseOperator] = ti.task.get_direct_relatives(True)

    # Making a set of the upstream tasks can come handy when dealing with many upstream tasks
    upstream_task_ids = {t.task_id for t in upstream_tasks}

    # Then we grab all of the failed task instance in the current run, which will get us tasks that some of might be un-related to this one
    failed_task_instances = dag_run.get_task_instances(state='failed')

    # That's why we intersect with the direct upstream relatives
    failed_upstream_task_ids = [failed_task.task_id for failed_task in failed_task_instances if failed_task.task_id in upstream_task_ids]

    # Finally we can stdout it, or do whatever we like to
    for failed_task_id in failed_upstream_task_ids:
        logging.info(f'The task "{failed_task_id}" has failed :(')
    

...

report_failed_task = PythonOperator(task_id='report_failed_task',
                                    python_callable=get_failed_upstream_tasks
                                    trigger_rule=TriggerRule.ONE_FAILED)

a >> report_failed_task
b >> report_failed_task
c >> report_failed_task
```

A few notes:

- I've set a `TriggerRule.ONE_FAILED` to activate this task only if something failed. However, it can be adjusted to run always, even with mixed results of success and failure
- I wouldn't be surprised if there was a simpler way
- `get_current_context().get('task')` instead of `ti.task` should also work, but I didn't test

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it's my version of Airflow doing it wrong but `get_direct_relatives(True)` didn't get me all the upstream operators.
I had to iterate on each direct relative to get them all.
Here's updated version of @mati.o:

```py
def get_failed_upstream_tasks():
    # We need both the current run and the current task instance 
    dag_run: DagRun = get_current_context().get('dag_run')
    ti: TaskInstance = get_current_context().get('ti')

    # This is what took me a while - to figure out that the direct relatives 
    # are defined on the Task and not on the TaskInstance. True - for upstream
    upstream_tasks: list[BaseOperator] = []
    direct_relatives: list[BaseOperator] = ti.task.get_direct_relatives(True)
    while (len(direct_relatives) > 0):
        dr: BaseOperator = direct_relatives.pop()
        upstream_tasks.append(dr)
        drs: list[BaseOperator] = dr.get_direct_relatives(True)
        direct_relatives.extend(drs)

    # Making a set of the upstream tasks can come handy when dealing with many upstream tasks
    upstream_task_ids = {t.task_id for t in upstream_tasks}

    # Then we grab all of the failed task instance in the current run, which will get us tasks that some of might be un-related to this one
    failed_task_instances = dag_run.get_task_instances(state='failed')

    # That's why we intersect with the direct upstream relatives
    failed_upstream_task_ids = [failed_task.task_id for failed_task in failed_task_instances if failed_task.task_id in upstream_task_ids]

    # Finally we can stdout it, or do whatever we like to
    for failed_task_id in failed_upstream_task_ids:
        logging.info(f'The task "{failed_task_id}" has failed :(')
    

...

report_failed_task = PythonOperator(task_id='report_failed_task',
                                    python_callable=get_failed_upstream_tasks
                                    trigger_rule=TriggerRule.ONE_FAILED)

a >> report_failed_task
b >> report_failed_task
c >> report_failed_task
```

Answer (score 0):

I tested this on Airflow 2.8.1. It uses `get_flat_relative_ids(upstream=True)`, which recursively retrieves all tasks upstream of the running task, instead of just the direct upstream tasks.

```py
@task()
def some_task(dag_run = None, ti = None): # These parameters are provided by the context automatically
    # Get all tasks that are upstream of this task
    upstream_task_ids: set[str] = ti.task.get_flat_relative_ids(upstream=True)
    # Get list of all tasks that have failed for this DagRun
    failed_task_instances: List[TaskInstance] = dag_run.get_task_instances(state='failed')
    # Get intersection of the sets to get upstream tasks that failed
    failed_upstream_task_ids = upstream_task_ids.intersection([task.task_id for task in failed_task_instances])
    
    # Whatever other processing you need
    ...

report_failed_task = some_task()
```